# How to Synchronize MySQL Database from an On Premise to Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I am new to Amazon RDS, and looking to get answer for my question below and couldn't find the answer on stackoverflow yet.

I have a MySQL Database on premise that I want to synchronize with the MySQL Database on Amazon RDS. I understand that replication is possible with Amazon RDS, but how about continuous synchronization? Say my existing local database has one transaction that has been made, I want to synchronize just that transaction, either immediately or by schedule, so that I don't need to replicate the whole thing to RDS.

1. Does RDS have this feature for MySQL or any other database?
2. If not, what tools should I be using? EC2 + ? ?
3. Or is there any database that supports this so I can just run the database on EC2?

Comment: *"I understand that replication is possible with Amazon RDS, but how about continuous synchronization?"*  **That's what replication is**... continuous synchronization, one transaction at a time... but you need an initial data load so that the two systems begin in an identical state.

Comment: i thought replication was more like a one time replication, not continuous. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best (first) option should probably be the AWS Database Migration Service. This is a migration service for exactly your use-case.

If uptime is less of an issue, you could always do a mysql_dump, move that to an EC2 instance and load that into an RDS instance.

Comment: unfortunately my internet data cost would be very high to do mysql_dump and uploading it to EC2, daily. I will definitely check your first option. I didn't know they had that. Thanks @Exelian